# which package publishes odom? ROS Hydro + turtlebot

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Sorry to disturb everyone.**

**But I want to know where the odom is published, as I want to record the odom message without the help of topic. I have searched over and over again, but still no found...**

**Heartfelt thanks to you!!   And sorry to my poor English...**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201568/which-package-publishes-odom?-ros-hydro-+-turtlebot/) by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2015-01-22**:
Topics are an essential communications resource in ROS. I'm assuming that you mean that you'd like to save/store the data from odom not just "look" at it with rostopic? (Can you clarify what you need?)

**Comment by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on 2015-01-24**:
@SL Remy

I am really sorry!  Thank you!
I want to save the odom data before it is published, as my teacher told me that the ros topic would cost more time, which will lead to the poor real-time of the odom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to record the odometry file in a .csv file do the following in different terminals:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch //launches roscore along with other turtlebot nodes


rosbag record -j -O house_bag /mobile_base/commands/velocity /odom //records the velocity and odometry topics and creates a .bag file named "house_bag"


//do some moving around with your turtlebot

rostopic echo -b house_bag.bag -p /odom > house_odom.csv //After you are done, this command exports the odometry csv file out of "house_bag.bag"
```

---

Originally posted by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) with karma: 290 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2